# Ember.js: Upload file component

Tags: ember.js

I need to create an Ember component to select a file.
My page will include multiple "upload component"

I have read a post trying to implement that: ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200000/file-upload-with-ember-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200000/file-upload-with-ember-data/)) BUT the UploadFileView is directly linked to the controller.
I would like to have something more generic...

I would like to remove the App.StoreCardController.set('logoFile'..) dependency from the view or pass the field (logoFile) from the template...

Any idea to improve this code ?

```
   App.UploadFileView = Ember.TextField.extend({
    type: 'file',
    attributeBindings: ['name'],
    change: function(evt) {
      var self = this;
      var input = evt.target;
      if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        App.StoreCardController.set('logoFile', input.files[0]);
      }
    }
});
```

and the template:

```
{{view App.UploadFileView name="icon_image"}}
{{view App.UploadFileView name="logo_image"}}
```

Comment: I did reply to your comment btw -and just to clarify the UploadFileView is not a controller but instead a full blown custom view object. I honestly think you could modify the view I showed to make it more dynamic and allow your frontend to have a number of file upload inputs

Comment: Yep, the UploadFileView is a full view object.  As I'm not a ember.js expert, could you please help me to get the answer with a sample code ?

Answer (score 14):

I completed a full blown example to show this in action

https://github.com/toranb/ember-file-upload

Here is the basic handlebars template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="person">
{{view PersonApp.UploadFileView name="logo" contentBinding="content"}}
{{view PersonApp.UploadFileView name="other" contentBinding="content"}}
<a {{action submitFileUpload content target="parentView"}}>Save</a>
</script>
```

Here is the custom file view object

```
PersonApp.UploadFileView = Ember.TextField.extend({
    type: 'file',
    attributeBindings: ['name'],
    change: function(evt) {
      var self = this;
      var input = evt.target;
      if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var that = this;
        reader.onload = function(e) {
          var fileToUpload = reader.result;
          self.get('controller').set(self.get('name'), fileToUpload);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
      }
    }
});
```

Here is the controller

```
PersonApp.PersonController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  content: null,
  logo: null,
  other: null
});
```

And finally here is the view w/ submit event

```
PersonApp.PersonView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'person',
  submitFileUpload: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var person = PersonApp.Person.createRecord({ username: 'heyo', attachment: this.get('controller').get('logo'), other: this.get('controller').get('other') });
    this.get('controller.target').get('store').commit();
  }
});
```

This will drop 2 files on the file system if you spin up the django app

Comment: if I don't use Person view and submitFileUpload have inside controller, may it cause problems? For me inside controller this.get('logo') is null  @Toran Billups

Comment: `self.get('controller').set(self.get('name'), fileToUpload);` needs to be changed to `self.get('targetObject').set(self.get('name'), fileToUpload);`

Answer (score 10):

**EDIT** (2015.06): Just created a new solution based on a component.
This solution provides an upload button with a preview and remove icon.
P.S. The `fa` classes are [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/)

Component handlebars

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='components/avatar-picker'>
        {{#if content}}
            <img src={{content}}/> <a {{action 'remove'}}><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
        {{else}}
            <i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>
        {{/if}}

        {{input-image fdata=content}}
</script>
```

Component JavaScript

```
App.AvatarPickerComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    actions: {
        remove: function() {
            this.set("content", null);
        }
    }
});

App.InputImageComponent = Ember.TextField.extend({
    type: 'file',

    change: function (evt) {
        var input = evt.target;
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var that = this;

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var data = e.target.result;
                that.set('fdata', data);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
});
```

Usage example

```
{{avatar-picker content=model.avatar}}
```

---

**Old Answer**

I took  [Chris Meyers](http://chrismeyers.org/2012/06/12/ember-js-handlebars-view-content-inheritance-image-upload-preview-view-object-binding/) example, and I made it small.

Template

```
{{#view Ember.View contentBinding="foto"}}
    {{view App.FotoUp}}
    {{view App.FotoPreview width="200" srcBinding="foto"}}
{{/view}}
```

JavaScript

```
App.FotoPreview= Ember.View.extend({
    attributeBindings: ['src'],
    tagName: 'img',
});


App.FotoUp= Ember.TextField.extend({
    type: 'file',

    change: function(evt) {
        var input = evt.target;
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var that = this;

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                var data = e.target.result;
                that.set('parentView.content', data);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: This way I was only able to send binarydata for image to the server. Had to do a lot of fixing for server-side. IS there anyway I can send whole file object(temp file) for rails server(Carrierwave) ??

Comment: If you want to use multipart-formdata, you can use jQuery's .serialize() method on form.

Answer (score 1):

Marek Fajkus you cannot use JQuery's .serialize, it makes no mention of file uploads in the documentation at  [JQuery UI docs](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

However, you could use [JQuery Upload Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)

Actually it does mention it, it says:
". Data from file select elements is not serialized."

Answer (score 1):

In case of uploading multiple files, you may want to use

```
{{input type='file' multiple='true' valueBinding='file'}}
                          ^^^^
```

This is a solution that you would use in normal HTML upload.

Additionally, you can use `'valueBinding'` which will allow you to set up an observer against that value in your component.