# One way binding from DOM element to Controller property - Ember

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, ember.js

In my ember application I've a file input DOM element. I bind the value attribute of the element to a controller property.

I do this to know when the file input's value changes. But I don't want to set the value from the controller. I mean one way binding. DOM element to controller and not controller to DOM element.

Handlebar code :

```
{{input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*;capture=camera" id="newImage" value= imagePath}}
```

Controller :

```
App.ExampleController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    imagePath: null,
    imageChanged: function () {
        //Some Code
    }.observes('imagePath')
});
```

I need this because I get the following error

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to set the 'value' property on
>   'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may
>   only be programmatically set to the empty string. thrown by
>   jquery-1.11.1.min.js

Is there a way to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File inputs elements do not have a `value` attribute, you'll need to bind to the change event on the input and then access the `files` property.

see this answer for an implementation that might help you [Ember.js: Upload file component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923122/ember-js-upload-file-component)

Answer (score 1):

### Using Controller

You can make one way binding using observer in which you are going to set the value manually.

```
App.ExampleController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    imagePath: null,
    imagePathValue: null,

    _imageChanged: function () {
        this.set('imagePath', this.get('imagePathValue'));
    }.observes('imagePathValue')
});
```

with

```
{{input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*;capture=camera" id="newImage" value=imagePathValue}}
```

### Using View

```
App.ExampleView = Ember.View.extend({
   _imageChanged: function () {
       this.$().find('#imageFile').on('keypress paste', function() {
           this.set('controller.imagePath', this.value);
       }.bind(this));
   }.on('didInsertElement')
});
```

with

```
{{input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*;capture=camera" id="newImage" id="imageFile"}}
```

### Using Ember.Binding.oneWay

> One especially useful binding customization you can use is the
>   oneWay() helper. This helper tells Ember that you are only interested
>   in receiving changes on the object you are binding from.

```
App.ExampleController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    imagePath: Ember.Binding.oneWay("imagePathValue"),
    imagePathValue: null,
});

{{input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*;capture=camera" id="newImage" value=imagePathValue}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I can see this how one way binding is demonstrated in ember. But I meant to say a different thing. That is the changes in the DOM element should reflect in controller's property but the vice versa shouldn't happen.