# How: File Upload with ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I was wondering how to do a real file upload (save file to server) with ember.js

Are there any good examples?

Comment: A simpler way to do this would be to use [ember-uploader](https://github.com/benefitcloud/ember-uploader)

Comment: Found this interesting piece of code discussed in Ember NYC May 2015 meetup. https://github.com/tim-evans/ember-nyc-may-2015 Youtube video: https://youtu.be/sZs-VXWIDh0 Hope this too helps.

Answer (score 5):

See my answer from another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38844566/input-type-file-in-ember-js/40369335#40369335)

```
<input
  multiple="true"
  onchange={{action "upload"}}
  accept="image/png,image/jpeg,application/pdf"
  type="file"
/>

actions: {
  upload: function(event) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    let imageData;

    // Note: reading file is async
    reader.onload = () => {
      imageData = reader.result;
      this.set(data.image', imageData);

      // additional logics as you wish
    };

    if (file) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }
}
```

It just works.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the answers in the link below, you will understand how to do file upload and save to server with emberjs:

[File upload with Ember data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200000/file-upload-with-ember-data/13820443#13820443)

In the answer provided by 'Toran Billups' in the link above, the lines below, which I copied from his answer, do the saving to server:

```
var person = PersonApp.Person.createRecord({username: 'heyo', attachment: fileToUpload});

self.get('controller.target').get('store').commit()
```