# Send file to Ember controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

In ember `index.html` i use component to send action and get file

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/picture-upload">
    <input multiple="true" onchange={{action "upload"}}
    accept="image/png,image/jpeg,application/pdf"
    type="file"
    />
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="upload">
    {{picture-upload upload='upload'}}
    {{outlet}}
</script>
```

and in `app.js`

```
App.UploadController=Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions:{
    upload:function (event) {
     //here to get file
  }
}});

App.PictureUploadComponent=Ember.Component.extend({
  actions:{
    upload(){
      //i want to send file but this is not good value
      this.sendAction('upload',this);
    }
  }
});
```

but i don't know how to send event, i need something like  this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40370830/7476171),after that i want with ajax to send file to server,but problem is how to get file!

Answer (score 0):

In `PictureUploadComponent`

```
upload(event){
      //i want to send file but this is not good value
      this.sendAction('upload',event);
    }
```