# Ember.js value binding with HTML5 file upload

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

I am not far from it to get the file upload working with Ember-data. But I do not get the value binding right. Below the relevant code.

**This is the App.js**

```
App.LandcodeNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.store.createRecord('landcode');
    },
    actions: {
        saveLandcode: function () {
            this.currentModel.save();
        }
    }
});


// REST & Model
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'api'
});
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: 'App.ApplicationAdapter'
});

App.Landcode = DS.Model.extend({
    code: DS.attr('string'),
    image: DS.attr('string')
});

// Views
App.UploadFile = Ember.TextField.extend({
    tagName: 'input',
    attributeBindings: ['name'],
    type: 'file',
    change: function (e) {
        var reader, that;
        that = this;
        reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var fileToUpload = e.target.result;

            console.log(e.target.result); // this spams the console with the image content
            console.log(that.get('controller')); // output: Class {imageBinding: Binding,

            that.get('controller').set(that.get('name'), fileToUpload);
        };
        return reader.readAsText(e.target.files[0]);
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="landcode/new">
    Code: {{input value=code}}<br />
    Image: {{view App.UploadFile name="image" imageBinding="Landcode.image" }}
    <button {{action 'saveLandcode'}}>Save</button>
</script>
```

As you can see in the **HTML** part is that I try to bind the imagecontent to the Landcode model attribute image. Tried it also without capital L.

I think I cant bind the image as such, because it is a custom view object? And also normally it would bind automatically I think. Maybe I am just doing some things twice.

**References:**

1. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Binding.html
2. http://devblog.hedtek.com/2012/04/brief-foray-into-html5-file-apis.html
3. [File upload with Ember data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200000/file-upload-with-ember-data/13820443#13820443)
4. [How: File Upload with ember.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676546/how-file-upload-with-ember-js)
5. http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/file-uploads-is-there-a-better-solution/765
6. http://chrismeyers.org/2012/06/12/ember-js-handlebars-view-content-inheritance-image-upload-preview-view-object-binding/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I updated your code to the following:

```
App.LandcodeNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {        
        return this.store.createRecord('landcode');
    },
    actions: {
        saveLandcode: function () {
            this.currentModel.save();
        }
    }
});

// REST & Model
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'api'    
});

App.Landcode = DS.Model.extend({
    code: DS.attr('string'),
    image: DS.attr('string')
});

// views
App.UploadFile = Ember.TextField.extend({
    tagName: 'input',
    attributeBindings: ['name'],
    type: 'file',
    file: null,
    change: function (e) {
        var reader = new FileReader(), 
        that = this;        
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var fileToUpload = e.target.result;
            Ember.run(function() {
                that.set('file', fileToUpload);
            });            
        };
        return reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    }
});
```

In the `App.UploadFile` instead of reference the controller directlly, I set the `file` property. So you can bind your model property, with the view using:

```
{{view App.UploadFile name="image" file=image }}
```

The `Ember.run` is used to you don't have problems when testing the app.

Please give a look in that jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/LxEsF/

Just fill the inputs and click in the save button. And you will see in the browser console, the data that will be send to the server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The sending to the server worked! However, I edit your answer a little bit, this line of code I provided: `return reader.readAsText(e.target.files[0]);` was not correct. You have copied it in the answer, but the image was not a true base64 data string. To accomplish that, I changed that line to: `return reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);`

Comment: but in new ember view not supported,

Answer (score 1):

I found that using attaching a data URI to a model attribute didn't allow files more than about 60k to be uploaded. Instead I ended up writing a form data adapter for ember-data. This will upload all the model data using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects#Sending_files_using_a_FormData_object). Sorry that it's in CoffeeScript rather than JS but it's pasted from my blog post. You can read the whole thing at http://blog.mattbeedle.name/posts/file-uploads-in-ember-data/

```
`import ApplicationAdapter from 'appkit/adapters/application'`

get = Ember.get

FormDataAdapter = ApplicationAdapter.extend
  ajaxOptions: (url, type, hash) ->
    hash = hash || {}
    hash.url = url
    hash.type = type
    hash.dataType = 'json'
    hash.context = @

    if hash.data and type != 'GET' and type != 'DELETE'
      hash.processData = false
      hash.contentType = false
      fd = new FormData()
      root = Object.keys(hash.data)[0]
      for key in Object.keys(hash.data[root])
        if hash.data[root][key]
          fd.append("#{root}[#{key}]", hash.data[root][key])

      hash.data = fd

    headers = get(@, 'headers')
    if headers != undefined
      hash.beforeSend = (xhr) ->
        for key in Ember.keys(headers)
          xhr.setRequestHeader(key, headers[key])

    hash

`export default FormDataAdapter`
```