# Upload and resize/crop image with Ember

Tags: image-processing, file-upload, ember.js

I'm building an upload function for images following this post:

[Ember.js value binding with HTML5 file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19909267/ember-js-value-binding-with-html5-file-upload)

But i would like to make some changes to the selected image before it is uploaded to the server; in other words, i would like that when the user select for upload a 7 Megapixel image (5 MB), it is resized to a 640 x 480 (just a few KB) image (eventually cropped) and then uploaded;

anyone has done this?

Comment: This sounds like more of a generic javascript question than Ember specific. You could do something like what is mentioned in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262141/resize-image-with-javascript-canvas-smoothly

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cropper](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper).

[This Ember CLI addon](https://github.com/mhretab/ember-cli-image-cropper) wraps the jQuery Cropper into an ember component.

[You can find a demo here](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper)

**Example:**

```
// app/components/avatar-cropper.js
import imageCropper from 'ember-cli-image-cropper/components/image-cropper';

export default imageCropper.extend({
  //override default options of cropper
  aspectRatio: 1,
  minCropBoxWidth: 100,
  minCropBoxHeight: 100,
  cropperContainer: '.cropper-container > img',
  previewClass: '.img-preview',
  croppedAvatar: null,

  actions: {
    getCroppedAvatar: function() {
      var container = this.$(this.get('cropperContainer'));
      var croppedImage = container.cropper('getCroppedCanvas');
      this.set('croppedAvatar', croppedImage);
    }
  }
});
```

Hope this helps